# No "Visit Meta" on bicycles.se

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

On [bicycles.se/questons](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions), I've noticed for some time now that we have no "Visit Meta" section on the sidebar, and we *do* have questions with the [featured](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag. Is this because we haven't had a lot of action on meta lately, or is there some other reason?

Comment: It actually only appears on individual question pages, but you're right that it's not there; I'm not sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that -- configuration problem. It should be there now.